# Insert Modal on user first login

Tags: functions, wp-admin

Attempting to create a Welcome Modal for first time users on initial login to my Multisite network.
I'm using code from this tutorial https://wp-mix.com/wordpress-first-user-login/
I can see the User meta updating in the database, but the modal code will not insert when wrapped in this function. Modal code works otherwise.

I suspect it's either something to do with adding the function within the function, or a priority thing. But not sure where to go from here.

```
/**
 * Set User meta.
 */
function fyc_register_add_meta( $user_id ) {
    add_user_meta( $user_id, '_new_user', '1' );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'fyc_register_add_meta' );


/**
 * Loads pop-up on first login.
 */
function shapeSpace_first_user_login($user_login, $user) {

    $new_user = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_new_user', true );

        if ( $new_user ) {

        update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_new_user', '0' );

        /**
         * Embed modal in footer
         */
        function fsc_display_modal_first_login() { ?>

            <div class="welcome-modal">
                <header>
                    <h1>Welcome!</h1>
                </header>
            </div>

            <?php
        }
        add_action( 'in_admin_footer', 'fsc_display_modal_first_login' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'shapeSpace_first_user_login', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks got there eventually. Final working solution below.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `wp_login` comes at the end of the `wp_signon()` function. But that's not the end of things for logging a user in. After that, they are redirected (so that the auth cookie that is set during logon can be read).  As a result, the user is wisked away to a new page an your footer action is never fired.  So as written it will never work (hope it makes sense why).

You can just use your existing logic with the `in_admin_footer` action.  Your logic doesn't really need to determine if the user is completing a login or not because once they do log in the first time, the meta is changed.

This should resolve it:

```
/**
 * Set User meta.
 */
function fyc_register_add_meta( $user_id ) {
    add_user_meta( $user_id, '_new_user', '1' );
}
add_action( 'user_register', 'fyc_register_add_meta' );


/**
 * Loads pop-up on first login.
 */
function shapeSpace_first_user_login($user_login, $user) {

    $new_user = get_user_meta( $user->ID, '_new_user', true );

    if ( $new_user ) {

    update_user_meta( $user->ID, '_new_user', '0' ); ?>

        <div class="welcome-modal">
            <header>
                <h1>Welcome!</h1>
            </header>
        </div>

    <?php }
}
add_action( 'in_admin_footer', 'fsc_display_modal_first_login' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it took some playing and troubleshooting, but I got it working.
The second function did not like the arguments being passed in, so I ended up using get_current_user_id() to update the user login status.

(And decided to enqueue a JS file to launch the modal).

```
function fsc_new_user( $user_login, $user ) {
    if ( $new_user = get_user_meta( $user->id, '_new_user', true ) ) {
        // They've Logged In Before, set to 0.
        update_user_meta( $user->id, '_new_user', '0' );
    } else {
        // First Login, set it to 1.
        update_user_meta( $user->id, '_new_user', 1 );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_login', 'fsc_new_user', 10, 2 );



function fsc_display_modal_first_login() {

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // Get current total amount of logins (should be at least 1).
        $new_user = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_new_user', true );
        // If it's 1, it's their first time logging in, display the Modal.
        if ( '1' === $new_user ) {

            wp_enqueue_script( 'modal', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'js/flaunt-sites-core-welcome-modal.js', array(), 20190419, true );
            update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), '_new_user', '0' );

        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_footer', 'fsc_display_modal_first_login' );
```